# Why is vertical-align:middle not working like text-align:center

Tags: html, css

Can someone please tell me *why* `vertical-align:middle` Not working like `text-align:center` ?

I mean, why is it so hard to make it work?

I want to know why those W3 ppl don't make a `text-align:middle`

I'm asking why it's so hard to make the `vertical-align:middle` like `text-align:center`.

Comment: Did you try the search function? :o http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vertical-align+middle 4280 results ;)

Comment: You've got the wrong idea about how vertical-align is used I'm afraid. Try this article for more ideas on achieving what you want: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/ Allendar is right though - search first... there is tons on this topic.

Comment: I think you should post a specific code example of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Ouch, issues much? (edited your question; it won't help you to bring your message like that)

Comment: @Ofear - my link first explained WHY if you read it: "The values for vertical-align have meaning with respect to a parent inline element.
With a line of text the values are relative to the line-height.
With a table cell the values are relative to the table-height-algorithm, which usually means the height of the row.
Unfortunately vertical-align doesn’t apply to block-level elements like a paragraph inside a div, which is where most of us figure out it isn’t the be all solution to vertical centering."

Comment: @JoeSpurling As I said. Is it so hard to make a `text-align:middle` in HTML6 or something like this?

Comment: This isn't an appropriate SO question. But essentially vertical-align doesn't play nicely with flow layout, which is strictly top-to-bottom, so it can only be used in certain, well controlled circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vertical-align attribute is for inline elements only. It will have no effect on block level elements, like a div or a paragraph.If you would like to vertically align an inline element to the middle just use this.

Refer this Link : http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align:center
```

means put the text in the center of the width of the `<p>` tag for example

```
vertical-align:middle
```

means. Put the `<p>` in the center (middle) of the height of the the parent tag `<div>` for example. Which means you need to increase the height of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical align aligns like by height like this:

```
___________________________
Some text aligned top

Some text aligned middle

Some text aligned bottom
__________________________
```

Help with horizontal align can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: thanks, But I asked why it's not working like it. Not how. I wanted to know why those W3 ppl don't make a `text-align:middle`